# How to find the position of multiple words in a string using strpos() function?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to find the position of multiple words in a string.

Forexample :

```
$str="Learning php is fun!";
```

I want to get the posion of **php** and **fun** .

And my expected output would be :-

1) The word **Php** was found on 9th position

2) The word **fun** was found on 16th position.

Here is the code that I tried, but it doesn't work for multiple words.

```
<?Php
$arr_words=array("fun","php");
$str="Learning php is fun!";
$x=strpos($str,$arr_words);
echo The word $words[1] was found on $x[1] position";
echo The word $words[2] was found on $x[2] position";
```

Does someone know what's wrong with it and how to fix it?

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't load an array of string words inside `strpos`, you could just invoke `strpos` twice, one for `fun` and one for `php`:

```
$arr_words = array("fun","php");
$str = "Learning php is fun!";
$x[1] = strpos($str,$arr_words[0]);
$x[2] = strpos($str,$arr_words[1]);
echo "The word $arr_words[0] was found on $x[1] position <br/>";
echo "The word $arr_words[1] was found on $x[2] position";
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kd1s6D)

Or loop the word array:

```
$arr_words = array("fun","php");
$str = "Learning php is fun!";
foreach ($arr_words as $word) {
    if(($pos = strpos($str, $word)) !== false) {
        echo "The word {$word} was found on {$pos} position <br/>";
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fJnYO9)

Answer (score 3):

To supplement the other answers, you can also use regular expressions:

```
$str="Learning php is fun!";

if (preg_match_all('/php|fun/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        echo "The word {$match[0]} found on {$match[1]} position\n";
    }
}
```

See also: [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

Comment: This is perfect

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="Learning php is fun!";
$data[]= explode(" ",$str);
print_r($data);//that will show you index

foreach($data as $key => $value){
 if($value==="fun") echo $key;
 if($value==="php") echo $key;
}
```

Key is the exact position but index start with 0 so keep in mind to modify your code accordingly, may be `echo $key+1` (a number of ways, depends on you).

Answer (score 1):

Just another answer:

```
<?php
$arr_words=array("fun","php");
$str="Learning php is fun!";

foreach($arr_words as $needle) {
    $x = strpos($str, $needle);
    if($x)
        echo "The word '$needle' was found on {$x}th position.<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were doing it in a wrong way check the function

```
strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

> **haystack**
>   The string to search in.
>
> **needle**
>   `If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.`
>
> **offset**
>   If specified, search will start this number of characters counted from the beginning of the string.

Refer [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Here within your example

```
$arr_words=array("fun","php");
$str="Learning php is fun!";
$x=strpos($str,$arr_words);
```

`$arr_words` is an **array** not a **`string`** or not an **`integer`**

so you need to loop it or need to manually pass the `key` as

```
$x[1] = strpos($str,$arr_words[0]);
$x[2] = strpos($str,$arr_words[1]);
```

or

```
foreach($arr_words as $key => $value){
     $position = strpos($str,$value);
     echo "The word {$value} was found on {$position}th position"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use function *strpos* if the second params is an array.
This is easiest way:

```
<?php
     $words = array("php","fun");
     $str = "Learning php is fun!";
     foreach ($words as $word) {
         $pos = strpos($str, $word);
         // Found this word in that string
         if($pos) {
             // Show you message here
         }
     }
```